# Putting a datatable in a shinyjs modal

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am using Shiny with the Shiny Semantic library to make the app look nice. The standard Shiny pop-up message using  showModal(modalDialog()) doesn't work with Semantic UI, so I have resorted to shinyjs to use some javascript to allow modals. With a js modal defined globally, how do I integrate a datatable into the modal? Here is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny.semantic)
library(DT)

modal.js = "$('.ui.modal')
.modal('show')
;"

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_table = DT::renderDataTable({
    head(iris)
  })
  observeEvent(input$open_modal, {
    runjs(modal.js)
  })
}

ui <- semanticPage(
  suppressDependencies("bootstrap"),
  useShinyjs(),
  div(class = "ui modal",
      div(class="header", 'Modal header'),
      p('Placing DT::dataTableOutput("my_table") here fails.
         If it was displayed, I would select a row and return the value to a reactiveValue.')
  ),
  div(class = "ui basic button action-button", id = "open_modal", "Open modal ui"),
  div(class = "ui raised segment", DT::dataTableOutput("my_table"))
)

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue today and managed to find a way to resolve this. When the modal opens in `shiny.semantic` the datatable output is still classed as not visible. To fix this you just need to add in an extra line to the JavaScript:

```
$('#my_table').show().trigger('shown');
```

You'll need to add some more JS if you want to hide it again when closed, but that might be better in the UI using `tags$script()` instead of in the server.

Updated app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny.semantic)
library(DT)

modal.js <- "$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
             $('#my_table').show().trigger('shown');"

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_table = DT::renderDataTable(head(iris))
  observeEvent(input$open_modal, runjs(modal.js))
}

ui <- semanticPage(
  suppressDependencies("bootstrap"),
  useShinyjs(),
  div(
    class = "ui modal",
    div(class = "header", "Modal header"),
    div(class = "content", div(class = "ui raised segment", DT::dataTableOutput("my_table")))
  ),
  div(class = "ui basic button action-button", id = "open_modal", "Open modal ui")
)

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in your dataTableOutput

```
output$my_table = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(head(iris), class = "compact", escape = FALSE)   })
```