# Dropdown menu opened by default when modal dialog opens

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

Taking example from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115060/putting-a-datatable-in-a-shinyjs-modal), I added a dropdown menu to select table columns.

However, the list menu should be closed when the modal opens.

Is there a way using javascript or other to get the modal dialog opens with the dropdown menu closed by default?

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny.semantic)
library(DT)

modal.js <- "$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
             $('#my_table').show().trigger('shown');"

ui <- semanticPage(
    suppressDependencies("bootstrap"),
    useShinyjs(),
    div(
        class = "ui modal",
        div(class = "header", "Modal header"),
        div(class = "content",
            div(class = "ui raised segment",
                selectInput(inputId = "picker",
                            label = "Select column",
                            choices = names(iris),
                            selected = names(iris)[-1],
                            multiple=T),
                br(),
                DT::dataTableOutput("my_table")))
    ),
    div(class = "ui basic button action-button", id = "open_modal", "Open modal ui")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$my_table = DT::renderDataTable(head(iris[,input$picker]))
    observeEvent(input$open_modal, runjs(modal.js))
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the option `openOnFocus = FALSE` in `selectizeInput` as shown below.

```
selectizeInput(inputId = "picker",
                        label = "Select column",
                        choices = names(iris),
                        selected = names(iris)[-1],
                        options = list(openOnFocus = FALSE), 
                        multiple=T),
```